# What is Minecraft Preview?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is [Minecraft Preview](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4423653831821-Minecraft-Preview-FAQ), how is it different from the previous Beta system, what devices is it available on, and how can I join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Minecraft Preview

Minecraft Preview is a new development version of Minecraft: Bedrock Edition that is intended to replace the old Beta system. You can test out upcoming features that are still in development before they are released in the official retail (regular) version. It was announced on January 31st, 2022, so it is still very new and information will be changing very rapidly as is it is developed. You can read more about it on the [Minecraft Preview FAQ](https://Aka.ms/PreviewFAQ) page.

---

### Available Devices & How to Download

Minecraft Preview is currently available on iOS, Windows 10/11, and Xbox One and X|S. Follow the steps below for your device.

#### Windows

If you own Minecraft for Windows 10/11, you should be able to install Minecraft Preview by visiting [this link](http://Aka.ms/PreviewWindows). (If it's not working, refresh the page, and if you still don't see the <kbd>Install</kbd> button, try [this link](http://Aka.ms/PreviewWindowsFix) instead.)

Once it's downloaded, you should be able to open and play Minecraft Preview. If you would like to import worlds from the retail (regular) version of Minecraft, follow these steps:

1. Click the <kbd>Pencil</kbd> icon next to the world you want to export to open the world settings.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the <kbd>Game</kbd> settings panel, and select <kbd>Export World</kbd>.
3. You can choose any location to save it where you can easily access it.
4. Find the file you just saved (it should be called [WorldName].mcworld) and right click on it, and then select <kbd>Open with</kbd> and then <kbd>Minecraft Preview</kbd>.
5. Minecraft Preview should open if it is not already, and the world will import. You can safely delete the .mcworld file that you just created, as it's just a copy of your world.
6. Repeat these steps for any additional worlds. Remember, your worlds will stay in the retail version, you're just copying them over to Minecraft Preview.

#### iOS

On iOS, there is currently limited spots available, but Mojang will open up more over time. You can join by visiting [this link](https://testflight.apple.com/join/qC1ZnReJ). If there is an available spot, you will be prompted to download the TestFlight app (which is Apple's app beta system), from which you can download Minecraft Preview. Check out [Josh's Twitter](https://twitter.com/jorax79), the release manager at Mojang who is providing regular updates when new spots will open up.

#### Xbox

Currently, Minecraft Preview is open to everyone that is enrolled in the Xbox Insider program.

1. On your Xbox console, download the **Xbox Insider App** from the Microsoft Store if you haven't already and launch it. If you aren't already in the Xbox Insider Program, you'll need to sign up now, don't worry though, it's really easy. The Insider Program allows players to test games from other developers, and upcoming features for the Xbox operating system itself.
2. On the sidebar, open <kbd>Previews</kbd>, and then select <kbd>Minecraft Preview</kbd>.
3. Select <kbd>Join</kbd>, agree to the prompts, and wait for it to download.
4. You're finished! Minecraft Preview should appear on your home screen and in the Apps and Games library. You complete additional things like surveys about your experience in the <kbd>Activities</kbd> tab of the Xbox Insider App, but this is not required.

---

### Minecraft Preview vs. Minecraft Beta

The old Minecraft Beta system will slowly be phased out in favor of Minecraft Preview. A benefit of the new system are that it is entirely stand-alone and separated from the retail version, meaning you don't need to switch back and forth, and there isn't as much risk of losing data in the process. Additionally, it now supports iOS, meaning a larger playerbase can test out new features and provide feedback before they are released. It is likely that it will be released for Android soon, and PS4/5 and Switch may come in the future.

---

### Additional Information

As you're trying out all the new and exciting stuff in Minecraft Preview, make sure you report any bugs you experience in the [Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MCPE/). You can also leave feedback and feature requests on the [Feedback Page](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us).

I'll try my best to keep this updated, but for more constant info, check out Josh, the [Minecraft Release Manager's Twitter](https://twitter.com/jorax79). He's leading Minecraft Preview, and will announce when more spaces open up for iOS, and release other information like more supported devices. Thanks Josh!

---

Hopefully this helped you at least a little bit, and have fun Previewing!